# How to expand placeholder in one file and not expand in second file

Tags: gradle

I have two resource files. For 'x.properties' I want evaluate placeholder and I want keep 'please-not-modify.properties' unchanged

build.gradle

```
processResources {
  include "**/x.properties"
  filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [abc: 'ABC', version: '2.3.1'])
} 

processResources {
  include "**/please-not-modify.properties"
}
```

Unfortunately, both file have evaluated placeholders...

PS. You guessed, I'm Maven veteran :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use placeholders only in a single file from your resources, you should try to apply the filter to only subset of files from your resources, like:

```
processResources {
    filesMatching('**/x.properties') {
        filter ReplaceTokens, tokens: [
            abc: 'ABC', version: '2.3.1'
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is used a [filesMatching](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/AbstractCopyTask.html#filesMatching(java.lang.String,%20org.gradle.api.Action)) method of the ProcessResources task, which:

> Configure the FileCopyDetails for each file whose path matches the specified Ant-style pattern.

So, with it it is possible to provide an additional processing for only subset of the files, which are included in this task.